# Nested IF statements in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the following problem. In cell E10 whenever I enter a number >= 6, the formula returns `FALSE`. Here is what I have:

```
=IF(D10="Rogue",IF(E10<=5,IF(OR(F10="Trash",F10="Uncommon",F10="Common"),CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,33),"List-Rogue-1"),IF(E10>=6,IF(OR(F10="Trash",F10="Uncommon",F10="Common"),CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,33),"List-Rogue-1"),"Not above level 6")))))
```

Comment: An answer would be much more likely if you showed your inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: If I enter a number <= 5 it would pick a random word from a list of words #1 and if I enter a number >= 6 it would pick a random word from another list of words.

Comment: Looks like a nesting error. Have you tried the Evaluate Formula tool?

Comment: Yes, it terminates on the first `IF` statements because 6 <= 5 is false and thus returns FALSE and does not continue

Comment: Why do you have the `CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,33),"List-Rogue-1"),` in there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a final 'if false' statement. And its validating to that. In other words - as D10 isn't "Rogue" its skipping all of you other code and skipping straight to the false condition - and because there isn't one. Its just putting false.

As such, you either need to tweak the first condition "D10="Rogue" or add a final false condition.

Hope this helps

Comment: Where exactly should I add the false statement in this case?

Comment: Right before the last bracket. if you paste it into another cell at the top - it would probably show you an error suggesting it adds another bracket. It appears that its just that last false condition - so you need to put a comma before the last bracket then write a condition. I'd just type "test" or something first to see if it works.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the logic problem I have. I don't need to return false but the result of another function and I have already written what should be the false statement it just doesn't work.

Comment: It might not be a complete solution but I have made it work to what I approximate it should: 

=IF(D10="Rogue",IF(E10<=5,IF(OR(F10="Trash",F10="Uncommon",F10="Common"),CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,33),"List-Rogue-1"),IF(OR(F10="Trash",F10="Uncommon",F10="Common"),CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,33),"List-Rogue-1"),"Not above level 6"))))


You had added a seperate condition for over 6, instead of using it as false for under 5 - this created a redundancy and an extra level of convolution

Comment: Says it has an error at `RANDBETWEEN`. I don't however see it.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest, I'd probably use the inspector (FX button next to formula bar)  and click through and check each statement validates to what it should. Might help to write down the triangles on a bit of a paper.